# Align multiple ggplot2 plots with grid

Tags: r, data-visualization, ggplot2

## Context

I want to plot two ggplot2 on the same page with the same legend. http://code.google.com/p/gridextra/wiki/arrangeGrob discribes, how to do this. This already looks good. But... In my example I have two plots with the same x-axis and different y-axis. When the range of the the y-axis is at least 10 times higher than of the other plot (e.g. 10000 instead of 1000), ggplot2 (or grid?) does not align the plots correct (see Output below).

## Question

How do I also align the left side of the plot, using two different y-axis?

## Example Code

```
x = c(1, 2)
y = c(10, 1000)
data1 = data.frame(x,y)
p1 <- ggplot(data1) + aes(x=x, y=y, colour=x) + geom_line()

y = c(10, 10000)
data2 = data.frame(x,y)
p2 <- ggplot(data2) + aes(x=x, y=y, colour=x) + geom_line()


# Source: http://code.google.com/p/gridextra/wiki/arrangeGrob
leg <- ggplotGrob(p1 + opts(keep="legend_box"))
legend=gTree(children=gList(leg), cl="legendGrob")
widthDetails.legendGrob <- function(x) unit(3, "cm")
grid.arrange(
  p1 + opts(legend.position="none"),
  p2 + opts(legend.position="none"),
  legend=legend, main ="", left = "")
```

## Output

[image: Example image]

Comment: See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13294952/left-align-two-graph-edges-ggplot/13295880#13295880 ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't mind a shameless kludge, just add an extra character to the longest label in `p1`, like this:

```
p1 <- ggplot(data1) +
    aes(x=x, y=y, colour=x) +
    geom_line() + 
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(200, 1000, 200),
                       labels = c(seq(200, 800, 200), " 1000"))
```

I have two underlying questions, which I hope you'll forgive if you have your reasons:

1) Why not use the same y axis on both?  I feel like that's a more straight-forward approach, and easily achieved in your above example by adding `scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 10000))` to `p1`.

2) Is the functionality provided by `facet_wrap` not adequate here?  It's hard to know what your data structure is actually like, but here's a toy example of how I'd do this:

```
library(ggplot2)

# Maybe your dataset is like this
x <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2),
                y1 = c(0, 1000),
                y2 = c(0, 10000))

# Molten data makes a lot of things easier in ggplot
x.melt <- melt(x, id.var = "x", measure.var = c("y1", "y2"))

# Plot it - one page, two facets, identical axes (though you could change them),
# one legend
ggplot(x.melt, aes(x = x, y = value, color = x)) +
    geom_line() +
    facet_wrap( ~ variable, nrow = 2)
```

Comment: Agree faceting seems a better option for the example given. You can also add `scales = "free_y"` if the OP insists on having the y axis scales done independently.

Comment: Thanks @joran - couldn't remember how to do that.

Comment: adding spaces into the label worked only on the output of are. Once I ran it thru tikzdevice, the spaces are ignored.

Comment: I end up using the faceting. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 10):

A cleaner way of doing the same thing but in a more generic way is by using the formatter arg:

```
p1 <- ggplot(data1) +
    aes(x=x, y=y, colour=x) +
    geom_line() + 
    scale_y_continuous(formatter = function(x) format(x, width = 5))
```

Do the same for your second plot and make sure to set the width >= the widest number you expect across both plots.

Comment: In my version of ggplot2, the argument was "[labels](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/scale_continuous.html)" and not "formatter".

Answer (score 8):

**1.** Using [cowplot](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/vignettes/introduction.html) package:

```
library(cowplot)
plot_grid(p1, p2, ncol=1, align="v")
```

[image]

---

**2.** Using `tracks` from [ggbio](http://www.tengfei.name/ggbio/docs/man/tracks.html) package:

**Note:** There seems to be a bug, x ticks do not align. (tested on 17/03/2016, ggbio_1.18.5)

```
library(ggbio)
tracks(data1=p1,data2=p2)
```

[image]