# reduce space between grid.arrange plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

I asked a question [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13294952/left-align-two-graph-edges-ggplot) about grid arrange and got a terrific response.  I want to reduce the space between plots now but get an error.  First I present the code that works and then the error code (what I tried).  I can't actually find `grid.arrange` and have always assumed it comes from `gridExtra` but I may be incorrect.

so 2 parts:

1. How can I reduce space between plots with grid arrange
2. Where can I find documentation about `grid.arrange` (Baptiste I know you maintain gridExtra so please correct my thinking or use of the package if I'm not using it in the way it was intended.)

**Good code bad space**

```
require(ggplot2);require(gridExtra)
A <- ggplot(CO2, aes(x=Plant)) + geom_bar() +
    coord_flip() + ylab("")
B <- ggplot(CO2, aes(x=Type)) + geom_bar() +coord_flip() 


 gA <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(A))
 gB <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(B))
 maxWidth = grid::unit.pmax(gA$widths[2:3], gB$widths[2:3])
 gA$widths[2:3] <- as.list(maxWidth)
 gB$widths[2:3] <- as.list(maxWidth)
 grid.arrange(gA, gB, ncol=1)
```

**Bad code (my try)**

```
require(ggplot2);require(gridExtra)
A <- ggplot(CO2, aes(x=Plant)) + geom_bar() +
    coord_flip() + ylab("") + theme(plot.margin= unit(1, "cm"))
B <- ggplot(CO2, aes(x=Type)) + geom_bar() +coord_flip() 


 gA <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(A))
 gB <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(B))
 maxWidth = grid::unit.pmax(gA$widths[2:3], gB$widths[2:3])
 gA$widths[2:3] <- as.list(maxWidth)
 gB$widths[2:3] <- as.list(maxWidth)
 grid.arrange(gA, gB, ncol=1)
```

**The error:**

```
Error in `[.unit`(theme$plot.margin, 2) : 
  Index out of bounds (unit subsetting)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was misunderstanding ggplot:

```
require(ggplot2);require(gridExtra)
A <- ggplot(CO2, aes(x=Plant)) + geom_bar() +
    coord_flip() + ylab("") + theme(plot.margin= unit(c(1, 1, -1, 1), "lines"))
B <- ggplot(CO2, aes(x=Type)) + geom_bar() +coord_flip() + 
    theme(plot.margin= unit(rep(.5, 4), "lines"))


 gA <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(A))
 gB <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(B))
 maxWidth = grid::unit.pmax(gA$widths[2:3], gB$widths[2:3])
 gA$widths[2:3] <- as.list(maxWidth)
 gB$widths[2:3] <- as.list(maxWidth)
 grid.arrange(gA, gB, ncol=1)
```

Answer (score -3):

Yes,
The [doc](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/theme.html) says:
plot.margin |   margin around entire plot (unit with the sizes of the top, right, bottom, and left margins)