# r-grid.arrange. When I make the plots they overlap. How do I get them to not overlap

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make an arrangement of ggplots. I am able to set it up but the plots overlap. How do I fix this?

```
grid.arrange(NFL_Plot, NBA_Plot, MLB_Plot, NHL_lot,NASCAR_Plot, CBB_Plot, CFB_Plot, 
         ncol = 3, nrow = 3)`
```

This is what it looks like when I run the code
  [image: This is what it looks like when I run the code]

Comment: Where do they overlap? In the rstudio plot window or in the final plot? This link might be helpful to solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39508304/margins-between-plots-in-grid-arrange

Comment: Use shorter labels, use smaller fonts. But most of all think about using facets

Comment: @RichardTelford How would I use facet in this case? Each graph's x axis is different but otherwise except for labels they are the same.