# Margin above title in ggplot created with grid.arrange

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra, r-grid

I have two ggplots that I can created like this:

```
df1 = data.frame(x=1:10, y1=11:20, y2=21:30)
gg1 = ggplot(df1) + geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y1))
gg2 = ggplot(df1) + geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y2))
grid.arrange(gg1, gg2, top=textGrob("Here should be some space above",
                                    gp=gpar(fontsize=18,
                                            fontfamily="Times New Roman")))
```

Now the output looks like this:

[image]

One does not see it here as it is white on white, but I would like to create more space in the output-image above the title. And I'm not really sure on how to do it. Here is described on how to add space between the single plots [Margins between plots in grid.arrange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39508304/margins-between-plots-in-grid-arrange) , but I did not manage to just add space above the header.

Comment: how about using `padding=unit(1, "cm")` which adds a bit of space around the annotation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making use of `arrangeGrob` you could add some margin on top of your header via a `zeroGrob` like so:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)

df1 = data.frame(x=1:10, y1=11:20, y2=21:30)
gg1 = ggplot(df1) + geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y1))
gg2 = ggplot(df1) + geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y2))

title <- textGrob("Here should be some space above",
                  gp=gpar(fontsize=18, fontfamily="Times New Roman"))

# Add a zeroGrob of height 2cm on top of the title
title <- arrangeGrob(zeroGrob(), title, 
                    widths = unit(1, 'npc'), 
                    heights = unit(c(2, 1), c('cm', 'npc')),
                    as.table = FALSE)
grid.arrange(gg1, gg2, top = title)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Can you live with another package?

```r
library(patchwork)

plot_spacer()/ (gg1 + ggtitle("there is now space above")) / gg2 + plot_layout(heights = c(.5,1,1))
```

[image]

Or set the title margin in the first plot

```r
gg1 = ggplot(df1) + geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y1)) +
  ggtitle("there is now space above") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(margin = margin(t = 1, unit = "in")))

gg1 / gg2
```

[image]