# Combine ggplots but fix the size/ratio of the plots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two plots that I combine. `arrangeGrob()` squeezes them so that the size of the new image is the same as one alone. How can I arrange them while preserving the ratio/size?

```
require(ggplot2)
require(gridExtra)

dat <- read.csv("http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/data/fish.csv")

frqncy <- as.data.table(table(dat$child))#
frqncy$V1 <- as.numeric(frqncy$V1)

plot1 <- ggplot(frqncy, aes(x=V1, y= N)) +
    geom_histogram(stat="identity", binwidth = 2.5)
plot2 <- ggplot(frqncy, aes(x=V1, y= N)) +
    geom_density(stat="identity")

plot <- arrangeGrob(plot1, plot2)
```

`Plot` looks like

[image: Plots become smaller when combined]

I have not found any parameter in `ggplot()` or `arrangeGrob()` that fixes the ratio of the input.

Edit: Additional complications arise from the definition of axis labels in `arrangeGrob()`, i.e.

```
plot <- arrangeGrob(plot1, plot2, left="LHS label")
```

Then the new file will not automaticall shrink to the minimum height/width combination of `plot1` and `plot2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can control this when you output to a device. For example, a PDF file:

```
pdf("plot.pdf", width=5,height=8)
plot
dev.off()
```

[image]

Another option is to set a fixed ratio between the x and y coordinates in the plot itself using `coord_fixed(ratio=n)`, where `n` is the y/x ratio. This will set the relative physical length of the x and y axes based on the nominal value range for each axis. If you use `coord_fixed()` the graph will always maintain the desired aspect ratio no matter what device size you use for your output.

For example, in your case both graphs have x-range 0 to 3 and y-range 0 to 132. If you set `coord_fixed(ratio=1)`, your graphs will be tall and super skinny because the x-axis length will be 3/132 times the y-axis length (or to put it another way, 1 x-unit will take up the same physical length and 1 y-unit, but there are only 3 x-units and 132 y-units). Play around with the value of ratio to see how it works. A ratio of somewhere around 0.02 is probably about right for your graphs.

As an example, try the following code. Here I've set the ratio to 0.1, so now 1 x-unit takes up 10 times the physical length of each y-unit (that is, 0 to 3 on the x-axis has the same physical length as 0 to 30 on the y-axis).

```
plot1 <-ggplot(frqncy, aes(x=V1, y= N)) +
  geom_histogram(stat="identity", binwidth = 2.5) + 
  coord_fixed(ratio=0.1)
plot2 <- ggplot(frqncy, aes(x=V1, y= N)) +
  geom_density(stat="identity") +
  coord_fixed(ratio=0.1)

plot <- arrangeGrob(plot1, plot2)

pdf("plot.pdf", 5,8)
plot
dev.off()
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

there are several other options, depending on what you want*

```
library(ggplot2)
p = qplot(1, 1)
grid.arrange(p, p, respect=TRUE) # both viewports are square
grid.arrange(p, p, respect=TRUE, heights=c(1,2)) # relative heights

p1 = p + theme(aspect.ratio=3)
grid.arrange(p,p1, respect=TRUE) # one is square, the other thinner
```

*: the aspect ratio is often not a well-defined property of plots (unless set manually), because the default is to extend the plot to the available space defined by the plot window/device/viewport.

Comment: `respect=TRUE`, that's all I needed. I wonder why it's not in the documentary.

Comment: package author's laziness, if you ask me

Comment: I have to admit I was to early in my enthusiasm. `Plot` (in your case `p`) is quadratic although the two plots in it are also quadratic. This means that the plots are much smaller while most of the file `plot`/`p` is white border. Resizing in the final document is useless.

Comment: i don't really get it. Do you have a minimal reproducible example to illustrate your problem (edit your question)?

Comment: Yes, I meant square. Sorry for the confusion. I think the problem comes from the fact that I add my axis labels in the `arrangeGrob()` environment (which wasn't part of the first version of the question).