# R ggplot facet -- shared y axis, multiple distinct x-axes

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, facet

I have a dataset consisting of 3 variables (a, b, c) and one response (d).

```
    df <- structure(list(a = c(0.9973, 0.9965, 1.002, 1.0019, 1.001, 1.0031, 
1.0005, 1.0009, 1.0007, 0.9977, 1.0004, 1.001, 0.9936, 0.9945, 
1.0056, 1.0004, 0.9969, 0.9977, 1.001, 0.9876), b = c(-4.0841, 
-4.216, -4.1469, -4.1418, -4.1919, -4.1953, -4.3314, -4.1205, 
-4.2449, -4.0841, -4.276, -4.3396, -4.2885, -4.1386, -4.0689, 
-4.2229, -4.3886, -4.2267, -4.0344, -4.6152), c = c(32.04, 18.52, 
26.01, 25.65, 21.44, 22.26, 21.8, 21.6, 17.38, 13.84, 20.19, 
27.66, 20.85, 18.71, 22.18, 17.25, 26.78, 28.08, 25.9, 16.68), 
    d = c(2241, 2231, 2231, 2220, 2218, 2216, 2210, 2204, 
    2202, 2194, 2157, 2028, 1853, 1850, 1770, 1755, 1679, 
    1673, 1673, 1645)), .Names = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20))
```

My goal is to use `facet` in `ggplot2` to create a plot with a common y-axis of d, and three facets having x-axes of a, b, and c respectively -- in other words, d vs a, d vs. b, and d vs. c adjacent to each other with a common y-axis.  An approximation of my goal can be shown in base R with:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
plot(df$a, df$d)
plot(df$b, df$d)
plot(df$c, df$d)
```

I'd like to do this with ggplot and without repeating the y-axis.  I've seen similar plots, but they usually involve one x-axis repeated several times.  I've tried to `melt` the data (i.e. from `reshape2`) but I haven't come up with an orientation that works for me.

It would also be visually desirable to have each of d vs. a, d vs. b, and d vs. c be a different color.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14743060/r-ggplot-graphs-sharing-the-same-y-axis-but-with-different-x-axis-scales

Answer (score 3):

You're on the right track. We need to convert `df` to long format (`tidyr::gather` for example) then use `ggplot::facet_grid` to get the desired plot

```r
df <- structure(list(a = c(0.9973, 0.9965, 1.002, 1.0019, 1.001, 1.0031, 
  1.0005, 1.0009, 1.0007, 0.9977, 1.0004, 1.001, 0.9936, 0.9945, 
  1.0056, 1.0004, 0.9969, 0.9977, 1.001, 0.9876), b = c(-4.0841, 
  -4.216, -4.1469, -4.1418, -4.1919, -4.1953, -4.3314, -4.1205, 
  -4.2449, -4.0841, -4.276, -4.3396, -4.2885, -4.1386, -4.0689, 
  -4.2229, -4.3886, -4.2267, -4.0344, -4.6152), c = c(32.04, 18.52, 
  26.01, 25.65, 21.44, 22.26, 21.8, 21.6, 17.38, 13.84, 20.19, 
  27.66, 20.85, 18.71, 22.18, 17.25, 26.78, 28.08, 25.9, 16.68), 
      d = c(2241, 2231, 2231, 2220, 2218, 2216, 2210, 2204, 
      2202, 2194, 2157, 2028, 1853, 1850, 1770, 1755, 1679, 
      1673, 1673, 1645)), 
  .Names = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-20))

library(tidyverse)

df_long <- df %>% 
  gather(key, value, a:c)

ggplot(df_long, aes(x = d, y = value, color = key)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(~ key) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(df_long, aes(x = d, y = value, color = key)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid(~ key)+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(df_long, aes(x = d, y = value, color = key, fill = key)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_grid(~ key)+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Created on 2018-06-07 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Thanks, that's close, but not quite right.  I need "d" to be the y-axis (common to all three plots), and then from right to left I want the plots to have a, b, and c respectively as the x-axis.  Unfortunately, simply flipping the x and y in the code produces an undesirable result: `ggplot(df_long, aes(x = key, y = d, color = key)) +
   geom_point() +
   facet_grid(~ key)`

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, Tung and Amanda for getting me on the right track.  The key is to use `facet_wrap` rather than `facet_grid`.  Once the data is in the proper long format as mentioned above:

```
library(tidyverse) 
df_long <- df %>% 
   gather(key, value, a:c)
```

then this version does the trick:

```
ggplot(df_long, aes(x = value, y = d, color = key)) +
    geom_point() +
    facet_wrap(~ key, scales="free_x")
```

Comment: You get the same result with `facet_grid(~ key, scales = "free_x")`