# R: Align plots with different x ranges

Tags: r, ggplot2, dataframe

I have two dataframes `dataA` and `dataB`, both of which contain a `time` and a `value` column. Time columns are closely related, but non-identical. Now, I generate two plots with ggplot, e.g.:

```
plotA <- ggplot(dataA) + geom_line(aes(x = time, y = value))
plotB <- ggplot(dataB) + geom_line(aes(x = time, y = value))
```

How can I use `grid.arrange` or a similar function to display the two plots vertically and so that x-axis labels and grid lines align?

Comment: Please make your code reproducible by adding sample data.

Comment: Does this [**post**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13294952/left-align-two-graph-edges-ggplot) help? Seems like a possible duplicate.

Comment: "Time columns are closely related, but non-identical." I'm seeking to align the values, not the plot areas.

Comment: It doesn't "plot" areas. It aligns the left end of the graph between the two and that's what I thought you wanted when you said "**x-axis** labels and grid lines **align**".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use facets to align the plots.

Firstly, both data sets need to be combined:

```
dataAB <- rbind(dataA[c("time", "value")], dataB[c("time", "value")])
```

A new column indicates the original data set:

```
dataAB$ind <- c(rep("A", nrow(dataA)), rep("B", nrow(dataB)))
```

Plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dataAB) + 
  geom_line(aes(x = time, y = value)) +
  facet_wrap( ~ ind, ncol = 1, scales = "free_y")
```

Comment: Wow, much better than I expected... Thanks