# arrangeGrob with gtable objects

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/13295880 I learned how to arrange two plots with aligned plot areas.

My question is:  How can I get an object of the arranged plots?

Example:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(gridExtra)

A <- ggplot(CO2, aes(x=Plant)) + geom_bar() +coord_flip() 
B <- ggplot(CO2, aes(x=Type)) + geom_bar() +coord_flip() 

gA <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(A))
gB <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(B))
maxWidth = grid::unit.pmax(gA$widths[2:3], gB$widths[2:3])
gA$widths[2:3] <- as.list(maxWidth)
gB$widths[2:3] <- as.list(maxWidth)

## works:
grid.arrange(gA, gB, ncol=1)

## does not work:
theplot <- grid.arrange(gA, gB, ncol=1, plot=FALSE)
```

Comment: there's no `plot` argument for `grid.arrange`

Comment: @baptiste There is in the help page of grid.arrange: `Value:

     return a frame grob; side-effect (plotting) if plot=T`

Comment: good catch, the help page hasn't been updated since the early version where this was dropped.

Comment: i've updated the help page (on github), and `grid.arrange` now also returns the grob invisibly.

Comment: Very nice!  That will be handy.  Much appreciated.  Unfortunately I do not have enough reputation to upvote a comment, sorry :-(

Comment: With this question, I have now gained enough reputation, so upvoted now.  Thanks again.

Comment: thanks, but I don't think upvoting comments matters much (as I understand, this feature is only present to prevent never-ending streams of "Me too!".)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use function `arrangeGrob()` to save both plots as object.

```
theplot <- arrangeGrob(gA, gB, ncol=1)
```

Comment: does not work for me: `Error in arrangeGrob(gA, gB, ncol = 1, plot = FALSE) : 
  input must be grobs!`