# How to align two plots with ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, gtable

I a trying to align two plots using `grid` but with no success. I have tried tweaking the themes so the plot border/size is the same but the plots do not align despite using the same y-coordinates.  For the example below i could use `annotation_custom` (a few examples on site) but this limits the quantity of text I can add. Any suggestions / amendments / alternatives are appreciated.

My ugly code

```
library(gridExtra)
library(ggplot2)

# Data
my.df<-data.frame(vars=paste("variable",letters[1:8],sep="-"),   
  est=seq(-0.2,0.5,0.1),ci.l=seq(-0.2,0.5,0.1)-0.5,ci.u=seq(-0.2,0.5,0.1)+0.5)
my.df$effect<-with(my.df,paste(round(est,1),"(",round(ci.l,2)," ,",round(ci.u,2),")"))                  


# Functions                  

gg.forrest<-function(data, x , y , ymin, ymax , opts=NULL)        {        
 my.min<-floor(data[[ymin]])
 my.max<-ceiling(data[[ymax]])

p<- ggplot(data, aes_string(x=x, y=y, ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax)) + 
    geom_pointrange() + 
    geom_hline(aes(x=0), lty=2) + 
    theme( axis.title.y=element_blank(),axis.ticks.y = element_blank(), axis.text.y=element_text(colour = "black")) +
   coord_flip() +
   theme(axis.text.y=element_text(hjust=0, size=15)) +
   theme( plot.margin = unit(c(1,2,1,1), "lines")) +
   theme(panel.border = element_blank()   ,panel.background = element_blank()) +
   geom_segment(aes_string(y=my.min,yend=my.max,x=0,xend=0))  + 
   opts

  p
} 



gg.forest.text<-function(data, x, label, opts=NULL) {  

  p<- ggplot(data, aes_string(x=0, y=x, label=label)) +  
     geom_text( hjust=0, size=4, colour="black") + 
#    coord_flip() +
     theme_bw() + 
     theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.border = element_blank()) +
#    theme(axis.title=element_blank(),axis.ticks = element_blank(), axis.text=element_blank()) +
    theme( axis.ticks = element_blank()) +
   scale_x_continuous( "",breaks=c(0),labels=c(" ")) +
   scale_y_discrete("",breaks=c(0),labels=c(" ")) +
   theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1,1,1,-3), "lines")) +
   opts

  p
}


# Output
p<-gg.forrest(my.df , "vars" , "est" , "ci.l" , "ci.u") 
p.eff<-gg.forest.text(my.df, "vars", "effect")

p.out<-arrangeGrob(p,p.eff,ncol=2 , widths=c(2,2/3))
print(p.out)
```

Comment: user20650 Normally you would flag it for moderator attention (which the moderators can then see) rather than comment and hope someone notices (you flag it by clicking 'flag' under your post, which allows you to then write a brief message about what you want to happen). In the interest of speed (since you may not still be on site to see this in time), I have flagged it for you.

Comment: My apologies; I got the impression you just hadn't realized how to do it.

Comment: Author requested migration.?//

Comment: possible duplicate of [left align two graph edges (ggplot)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13294952/left-align-two-graph-edges-ggplot)

Comment: i had looked at the links above but the problem is slightly different. In my example the plot margins line up but i cannot get the y values to line up across plots

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest the following,

```
library(gtable)
a <- ggplotGrob(p)
b <- ggplotGrob(p.eff)
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(gtable:::cbind_gtable(a, b, "first"))
```

but if you leave the default theme and margins of both plots, you'll notice that the alignment  is still problematic, simply because the y values are not identical in both plot panels.

Comment: Thanks. Im sure i am being daft but why are the y values not identical; they are both the same discrete variable names

Comment: in the first plot you add a segment and a line

Comment: Thanks Baptiste. I didn't think that would change things...lots to learn. So a work around to align theplots is to add a segment and horizontal line to the 2nd text plot and colour them white...they are now aligned. Thanks again.

Comment: you can use `geom_blank` or `expand_limits`

Comment: Yes, that's cleaner. Your comments have answered the question thanks again.