# ggplot: how to align two time-series plots on the x axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2, lubridate, gridextra, gtable

I am struggling with the following problem. Consider this (simple) example

```
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
library(gtable)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
options("digits.secs"=3)

time1 = c('2013-01-03 22:04:21.549', '2013-01-03 22:04:22.549', '2013-01-03 22:04:23.559', '2013-01-03 22:04:24.559' )
value1 = c(1,2,3,4)
data1 <- data_frame(time1, value1)
data1 <- data1 %>%  mutate(time1 = ymd_hms(time1))

time2 = c('2013-01-03 22:04:21.800', '2013-01-03 22:04:22.549', '2013-01-03 22:04:25.559', '2013-01-03 22:04:26.559' )
value2 = c(1,2,3,4)
data2 <- data_frame(time2, value2)
data2 <- data2  %>%  mutate(time2 = ymd_hms(time2))

g1 <- ggplot(data1, aes(x = time1, y = value1)) +geom_point()
g2 <- ggplot(data2, aes(x = time2, y = value2)) +geom_point()


graph_1 <- arrangeGrob(g1, g2, ncol=1)
grid.draw(graph_1)
```

which gives

[image]

as you can see the x- axis is not properly aligned. 
Any ideas how to do that? Alternative solutions like [How to align two plots with ggplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17388786/how-to-align-two-plots-with-ggplot) do not work here.

Many thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either use the same limit for both plots (first) or use the `facet_grid` to align the range for plots (second).

```
# first method
mx <- ymd_hms("2013-01-03 22:04:21.000")
mn <- ymd_hms("2013-01-03 22:04:27.000")
grid.arrange(g1 + scale_x_datetime(limits=c(mx, mn)),
             g2 + scale_x_datetime(limits=c(mx, mn)))
```

[image]

```
# second method
names(data1) <- c("time", "value")
names(data2) <- c("time", "value")
df <- bind_rows(first=data1, second=data2, .id="group")
ggplot(df, aes(x=time, y=value)) + geom_point() + facet_grid(group ~ .)
```

[image]

Comment: hi @JasonWang your nice (first) solution breaks if the units of the `y axis` contain a different number of digits. say `value2 = c(100,200,300,400)`. Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: I think the better way is to use the second one with `facet_grid(group ~ ., scales="free_y")`. For the first one, the way I come up with is to adjust the length of the y label by `scale_y_continuous(labels=function(x) {paste0("00", x)})`.

Comment: Or you need to figure out what the space is and use the `theme` to adjust the margin.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the limits of both plots to the range of the data:

```
xmin <- ymd_hms(min(time1,time2))
xmax <- ymd_hms(max(time1,time2))

g1 <- ggplot(data1, aes(x = time1, y = value1)) + geom_point() +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank()) + xlim(xmin, xmax)

g2 <- ggplot(data2, aes(x = time2, y = value2)) + geom_point() +
  xlim(xmin, xmax)
```

[image]