# ggplot2 and ggdendro - plotting color bars under the node leaves

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, ggdendro

Currently I'm using `ggplot2` and `ggdendro` to plot dendrograms. However Now I'm in need to plot a discrete variable under the leaves along with the labels.

For instance, in a publication (Zhang et al., 2006) I saw a dendrogram like this (notice th color bar under the leaf labels):

[image: Example dendrogram]

I'm interested in doing the same with ggdendro + ggplot2, using data which I have already binned. Is this possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, you need to make dataframe for the color bar. For example I used data `USArrests` - made clustering with `hclust()` function and saved the object. Then using this clustering object divided it in cluster using function `cutree()` and saved as column cluster. Column `states` contains labels of clustering object `hc` and the levels of this object are ordered the same as in output of `hc`.

```
library(ggdendro)
library(ggplot2)
hc <- hclust(dist(USArrests), "ave")
df2<-data.frame(cluster=cutree(hc,6),states=factor(hc$labels,levels=hc$labels[hc$order]))
head(df2)
           cluster     states
Alabama          1    Alabama
Alaska           1     Alaska
Arizona          1    Arizona
Arkansas         2   Arkansas
California       1 California
Colorado         2   Colorado
```

Now save as objects two plots - dendrogram and colorbar that is made with `geom_tile()` using `states` as x values and `cluster` number for colors. Formatting is done to remove all axis.

```
p1<-ggdendrogram(hc, rotate=FALSE)


p2<-ggplot(df2,aes(states,y=1,fill=factor(cluster)))+geom_tile()+
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0))+
  theme(axis.title=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks=element_blank(),
        axis.text=element_blank(),
        legend.position="none")
```

Now you can use answer of @Baptiste to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13294952/left-align-two-graph-edges-ggplot) to align both plots.

```
library(gridExtra)

gp1<-ggplotGrob(p1)
gp2<-ggplotGrob(p2)  

maxWidth = grid::unit.pmax(gp1$widths[2:5], gp2$widths[2:5])
gp1$widths[2:5] <- as.list(maxWidth)
gp2$widths[2:5] <- as.list(maxWidth)

grid.arrange(gp1, gp2, ncol=1,heights=c(4/5,1/5))
```

[image]