# Specify plot height in plot_grid with 'hv' aligment: cowplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, gtable, cowplot

I have been using the plot_grid command from cowplot to arrange my plots. I use the labeling feature, and my plots all look the same in that regard. However, when I 'hv' align some plots that have very different y-axis limits, such as the one below, it appears the height of the plot with shortest range of y is used.

[image: smooshed plot from cowplot hv aligned]

If I just 'v' align the plot it looks better in some respects, but it is hard to resize the plot and have the labels looking good. I'd prefer the plot height not consider the x-axis labels, etc, like above.

[image: v aligned plot]

Using [gtables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27408589/1670053), I can get the desired width/height (below), but these leaves me without the consistent labels across all the figures in a document. Can I use the 'hv' alignment with cowplot and specify which plot height to use?

[image: nice plot, no labels]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(scales)
library(grid)
library(cowplot)

data(iris)

iris <- iris %>% mutate(Petal.Width2 = ifelse(Species == "setosa", Petal.Width * 75, Petal.Width))

p1 <- ggplot(data=iris, aes(x = factor(Species), y=Sepal.Width)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  labs(x = NULL, y = "Plot One") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(), 
        axis.title.y = element_text(vjust=1), plot.margin=unit(c(2,2,0,2),"mm"))

p2 <- ggplot(data=iris, aes(x = factor(Species), y=Petal.Width2)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  labs(x = NULL, y = "Plot Two") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(), 
        axis.title.y = element_text(vjust=1), plot.margin=unit(c(0,2,0,2),"mm"))
p3 <- ggplot(data=iris, aes(x = factor(Species), y=Petal.Length*0+.01)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  labs(x = "SPECIES", y = "The Third plot") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent) +
  theme( axis.title.y = element_text(vjust=1, color="blue"), plot.margin=unit(c(0,2,0,2),"mm"),
         axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust=1, vjust=1,face ="italic", size=10))

plot_grid(p1,p2,p3,ncol=1, align="v", labels=c("A", "B", "C"))

# https://stackoverflow.com/a/27408589/1670053
plots <- list(p1, p2, p3)
grobs = lapply(plots, ggplotGrob)
g = do.call(rbind, c(grobs, size="first"))

g$widths = do.call(unit.pmax, lapply(grobs, "[[", "widths"))
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g)
```

Answer (score 4):

it's easy as to add labels,

```
plots <- list(p1, p2, p3)
grobs = lapply(plots, ggplotGrob)
library(gridExtra)
g = do.call(rbind, grobs) #  uses gridExtra::rbind.gtable
panels <- g$layout[g$layout$name=="panel",]

g <- gtable::gtable_add_grob(g, lapply(LETTERS[1:nrow(panels)],
                                       textGrob, vjust=1, y=1, 
                                       gp=gpar(fontface=2)), 
                             t=panels$t, l=2)

grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g)
```

[image]

Comment: This looks swell. However, I receive the error message "Error: 'rbind' is not an exported object from 'namespace:gridExtra'". Modifying the code from `g = do.call(gridExtra::rbind, grobs)`  to `g = do.call(rbind, c(grobs, size="first"))` works though.

Comment: I am having difficulty adjusting the position of the labels, when I modify `vjust= ` and/or `y= ` the labels do not appear to change their positions.

Comment: 1) my bad, it should work now; 2) strange, y=0.5 should bring them to the middle of the plot panels (vertically)

Comment: Error: 'rbind.gtable' is not an exported object from 'namespace:gridExtra'

Comment: you probably have an old version of gridExtra