# uniform panel width across multiple plots using grid.arrange

Tags: r, ggplot2

When displaying several plots via `facet_wrap(..., ncol = 1)`, the resulting plot widths are equal (even thou their axes texts differ in length).

Is it possible to achieve uniform widths (like in the left picture) using grid.arrange?

[image]

Fig.: `facet_wrap` on the left, `grid.arrange` on the right.

Comment: See [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13295880/496488) for a way to do that.

Comment: These certainly seem very closely related.  I'm not 100% sure whether it counts as a duplicate. I'd like the OP to weigh in on whether the linked answer actually works in this case ... can you give a reproducible example?

Comment: Seems fairly identical to me, but I will defer hammering it in deference to Ben's advice. (I just saw a question for which I had tested code, with an answer in two lines of code, closed as "too broad".)

Comment: Interesting. Which of the `grob$widths` specifies the width of the main panel? Can I set it to some arbitrary value, rather than extract the value from other plots? If yes, how?

Comment: don't know, and the results look a little inscrutable (try printing out `maxWidth` ...).  Try experimenting?

Comment: gtable:::rbind_gtable is usually the way to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirming that [the linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13295880/496488) actually works for this case:

Make up some data:

```
d <- data.frame(lab=c(paste("very very very very long label ......",1:2),
                      paste("sL",1:2)),
                f=rep(c("A","B"),each=2))

d$z <- 1:4

library("ggplot2"); theme_set(theme_bw())
library("gridExtra")
```

Generate two plots:

```
g1 <- lapply(split(d,d$f),
             function(dd) 
                 ggplot(dd,aes(x=lab,y=z))+geom_bar(stat="identity")+
                     coord_flip()+labs(x=""))
```

Now apply the suggested answer:

```
gA <- ggplotGrob(g1[[1]])
gB <- ggplotGrob(g1[[2]])
maxWidth <- grid::unit.pmax(gA$widths[2:5], gB$widths[2:5])
gA$widths[2:5] <- as.list(maxWidth)
gB$widths[2:5] <- as.list(maxWidth)
grid.arrange(gA, gB, ncol=1)
```

[image]