# Create different plots in R with same dimension ratio

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I created a function to create forest plots, which have labels on the y axis. I need to create a number of them to join in an external graphic program.

The plots images will have the same width but the height will change according to the number of y elements. To achieve this I first created a plot and manually set the image height (`i.h1`). Then I subtracted from `i.h1` the upper (`u.m`) and bottom (`b.m`) margin to get the plot height. Finally I divided the plot height by the number of y labels `n1` to get the one unit dimension `u = (i.h1 - b.m - u.m) / n1`.

To get the size of the subsequent image `h.i2` I just needed to `h.i2 = u * n2 + b.m + u.m`.

Here's is the result on a first image with 27 elements (counting the blank spaces) and a second image with 6 elements.

The second image is way higher than what it should be! (the purple lines are for comparison).

Furthermore the internal margin between the lower element and the x axis is different. So even if I use a different unit height I would end up with the labels in the 2 images not aligned.

[image]

I don't understand this behavior. Any hint?

Here's the code for saving the picture:

```
gt <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(plot)) #plot is a ggplot object
gt$layout$clip[gt$layout$name == "panel"] <- "off"
grid.draw(gt)

if (file != F) {
    w = 8.5
    h = .33 * max(data$yval) + 4 # .33 is the unit height and 4 are the margin

    dev.copy(pdf, if (file == T) sprintf("%s.pdf", gsub('\\n', '', title)) else file, width = w, height = h) # I use dev.copy because ggsave don't accept gtable plots.

    invisible(dev.off())
}
```

Comment: A reproducible example would be helpful. For now, does [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13295880/496488) provide any assistance?