# Plot over multiple pages

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, gridextra, radar-chart

I have the `facet_wrap` function to make multiple graphs (n=~51) but they all appear on one page. Now after searching, I found out that *ggplot2* can't place graphs on multiple pages.

Is there a way to do this? I looked at this question ([Multiple graphs over multiple pages using ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059826/multiple-graphs-over-multiple-pages-using-ggplot)) and tried out the code, with little success.

Here is my code for my graphs, it produces ~51 graphs on one page, making them very small and hard to see, if I could print this to 1 graph per page in a pdf, that would be great:

```
ggplot(indbill, aes(x = prey, y = weight), tab) +
geom_polygon(aes(group = load, color = capture), fill = NA, size = 0.75) +
facet_wrap(~ individual) +
theme(axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
    axis.text.x = element_text(size=rel(0.5)),
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y = element_blank()) +
xlab("") + ylab("") +
guides(color = guide_legend(ncol=2)) +
coord_radar()
```

If someone could write up a little code and explain it to me, that would be great.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

One option is to just plot, say, six levels of `individual` at a time using the same code you're using now. You'll just need to iterate it several times, once for each subset of your data. You haven't provided sample data, so here's an example using the `Baseball` data frame:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(vcd) # For the Baseball data
data(Baseball)

pdf("baseball.pdf", 7, 5)
for (i in seq(1, length(unique(Baseball$team87)), 6)) {
   print(ggplot(Baseball[Baseball$team87 %in% levels(Baseball$team87)[i:(i+5)], ], 
                  aes(hits86, sal87)) + 
    geom_point() +
    facet_wrap(~ team87) +
    scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, max(Baseball$sal87, na.rm=TRUE))) +
    scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0, max(Baseball$hits86))) +
    theme_bw())
}
dev.off()
```

The code above will produce a PDF file with four pages of plots, each with six facets to a page. You can also create four separate PDF files, one for each group of six facets:

```
for (i in seq(1, length(unique(Baseball$team87)), 6)) {
pdf(paste0("baseball_",i,".pdf"), 7, 5)
  ...ggplot code...
dev.off()
}
```

Another option, if you need more flexibility, is to create a separate plot for each level (that is, each unique value) of the facetting variable and save all of the individual plots in a list. Then you can lay out any number of the plots on each page. That's probably overkill here, but [here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35304121/496488) where the flexibility comes in handy.

First, let's create all of the plots. We'll use `team87` as our facetting column. So we want to make one plot for each level of `team87`. We'll do this by splitting the data by `team87` and making a separate plot for each subset of the data.

In the code below, `split` splits the data into separate data frames for each level of `team87`. The `lapply` wrapper sequentially feeds each data subset into ggplot to create a plot for each team. We save the output in `plist`, a list of (in this case) 24 plots.

```
plist = lapply(split(Baseball, Baseball$team87), function(d) {
  ggplot(d, aes(hits86, sal87)) + 
    geom_point() +
    facet_wrap(~ team87) +
    scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, max(Baseball$sal87, na.rm=TRUE))) +
    scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0, max(Baseball$hits86))) +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(plot.margin=unit(rep(0.4,4),"lines"),
          axis.title=element_blank())
})
```

Now we'll lay out six plots at time in a PDF file. Below are two options, one with four separate PDF files, each with six plots, the other with a single four-page PDF file. I've also pasted in one of the plots at the bottom. We use `grid.arrange` to lay out the plots, including using the `left` and `bottom` arguments to add axis titles.

```
library(gridExtra)

# Four separate single-page PDF files, each with six plots
for (i in seq(1, length(plist), 6)) {
  pdf(paste0("baseball_",i,".pdf"), 7, 5)
  grid.arrange(grobs=plist[i:(i+5)], 
               ncol=3, left="Salary 1987", bottom="Hits 1986")
  dev.off()
}

# Four pages of plots in one PDF file
pdf("baseball.pdf", 7, 5)
for (i in seq(1, length(plist), 6)) {
  grid.arrange(grobs=plist[i:(i+5)], 
               ncol=3, left="Salary 1987", bottom="Hits 1986")
}
dev.off()
```

Comment: Hi @eipi10! That worked wonderfully and was easy to understand! Although I am having one issue. It seems that the code doesn't like one of my individuals and I'm getting this error. It stops printing after it hits this individual 
`= list(grobs Error in gList(705-70773 = list(grobs = list(list(x = 0.5, y = 0.5,  : 
  only 'grobs' allowed in "gList"`

Any help would be great!

Comment: It there something about the data for that individual that results in a plot not being produced? If there's no plot, then the output of the plot code won't be a grob (graphics object).  For example, are all data missing for that individual or something like that? Try creating your plot but feed ggplot a data frame with just the data for that one individual and see what happens. Look at the data for that individual and see if there's something obviously different about it.

Comment: The plot was made when I used HubertL's suggestion, so I dunno. Either way, I understood your answer and it will help me in the future.

Thanks again!

Comment: This was super helpful to see. I had a situation where the plot I needed inside the for loop was just a regular call to ggplot() I had to assign this to an object and then say `print(my_plot)` in order to get it to save to the file.

Answer (score 31):

There are multiple ways to do the pagination: [ggforce](https://ggforce.data-imaginist.com/reference/facet_wrap_paginate.html) or [gridExtra::marrangeGrob](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/vignettes/arrangeGrob.html#multiple-pages-output). See also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50930640/786542) for another example.

#### ggforce:

```r
library(ggplot2)
# install.packages("ggforce")
library(ggforce)

# Standard facetting: too many small plots
ggplot(diamonds) +
  geom_point(aes(carat, price), alpha = 0.1) +
  facet_wrap(~cut:clarity, ncol = 3)
```

[image]

```r
# Pagination: page 1
ggplot(diamonds) +
  geom_point(aes(carat, price), alpha = 0.1) +
  facet_wrap_paginate(~cut:clarity, ncol = 3, nrow = 3, page = 1)
```

[image]

```r
# Pagination: page 2
ggplot(diamonds) +
  geom_point(aes(carat, price), alpha = 0.1) +
  facet_wrap_paginate(~cut:clarity, ncol = 3, nrow = 3, page = 2)
```

[image]

```r
# Works with grid as well
ggplot(diamonds) +
  geom_point(aes(carat, price), alpha = 0.1) +
  facet_grid_paginate(color~cut:clarity, ncol = 3, nrow = 3, page = 4)
```

[image]

#### gridExtra:

```r
# install.packages("gridExtra")
library(gridExtra)

set.seed(123)
pl <- lapply(1:11, function(.x) 
  qplot(1:10, rnorm(10), main=paste("plot", .x)))

ml <- marrangeGrob(pl, nrow=2, ncol=2)

## non-interactive use, multipage pdf
## ggsave("multipage.pdf", ml)
## interactive use; calling `dev.new` multiple times
ml
```

[image][image][image]

<sup>Created on 2018-08-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0.9000).</sup>

Answer (score 2):

something like :

```
by(indbill, indbill$individual, function (x){
    ggplot(x, aes(x = prey, y = weight), tab) +
    geom_polygon(aes(group = load, color = capture), fill = NA, size = 0.75) +
    theme(axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size=rel(0.5)),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank()) +
    xlab("") + ylab("") +
    guides(color = guide_legend(ncol=2)) +
    coord_radar()
}
```