# Combining `for loop` and ggplotGrob

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I just wanted to plot multiple facets using `ggplot2` in combination with `for loop` and found the solution in this post[ggplot2-plots-over-multiple-pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39736655/ggplot2-plots-over-multiple-pages?noredirect=1&lq=1).

However, I want to modify appearances of these facets with `ggplotGrop` for reducing the strip size of facets after this `for loop`.

I am providing here reproducible example of previous question for only plotting `facets`

```
library(ggplot2)
library(vcd) # For the Baseball data
data(Baseball)

pdf("baseball.pdf", 7, 5)

aa<- for (i in seq(1, length(unique(Baseball$team87)), 6)) {
       print(ggplot(Baseball[Baseball$team87 %in% levels(Baseball$team87)[i:(i+5)], ], 
                      aes(hits86, sal87)) + 
        geom_point() +
        facet_wrap(~ team87) +
        scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, max(Baseball$sal87, na.rm=TRUE))) +
        scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0, max(Baseball$hits86))) +
        theme_bw())
    }
    dev.off()
```

want to implement `ggplotGrob` to reduce the strip size.

```
library(gridExtra)
         library(grid)
         g = ggplotGrob(aa)

         pos =  c(unique(subset(g$layout, grepl("panel", g$layout$name), select = t)))
         for(i in pos) g$heights[i-1] = unit(0.4,"cm")

         grobs = which(grepl("strip", g$layout$name))
         for(i in grobs) g$grobs[[i]]$heights <-  unit(1, "npc") 

        grid.draw(g)
        dev.off()
```

> Error in plot_clone(plot) : attempt to apply non-function

I just wonder how to implement `ggplotGrop` to that for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main probleme is that you're using `ggplotGrob` on an the wrong object.
You have to use it inside each loop.
Then you must `grid.arrange` to make the multipage pdf

First method: with a trick as `ggplotGrob` create a blank page

```
pdf("baseball.pdf", 7, 5)

for (i in seq(1, length(unique(Baseball$team87)), 6)) {
  temp <- ggplot(Baseball[Baseball$team87 %in% levels(Baseball$team87)[i:(i+5)], ], 
               aes(hits86, sal87)) + 
          geom_point(na.rm=TRUE) + ## to avoid warnings
          facet_wrap(~ team87) +
          scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, max(Baseball$sal87, na.rm=TRUE))) +
          scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0, max(Baseball$hits86))) +
          theme_bw()
  pdf(file=NULL) ## because ggplotGrob will create a blank page
  g <- ggplotGrob(temp)
  pos =  c(unique(subset(g$layout, grepl("panel", g$layout$name), select = t)))
  for(i in pos) g$heights[i-1] = unit(0.4,"cm")

  grobs = which(grepl("strip", g$layout$name))
  for(i in grobs) g$grobs[[i]]$heights <-  unit(1, "npc") 
  dev.off() ## to close the fake device
  grid.arrange(g)



}

dev.off()
```

Second method: to avoid using fake device

```
plotlist <- list()
j <- 1

for (i in seq(1, length(unique(Baseball$team87)), 6)) {
  temp <- ggplot(Baseball[Baseball$team87 %in% levels(Baseball$team87)[i:(i+5)], ], 
               aes(hits86, sal87)) + 
          geom_point(na.rm=TRUE) +
          facet_wrap(~ team87) +
          scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, max(Baseball$sal87, na.rm=TRUE))) +
          scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0, max(Baseball$hits86))) +
          theme_bw()
  g <- ggplotGrob(temp)
  pos =  c(unique(subset(g$layout, grepl("panel", g$layout$name), select = t)))
  for(i in pos) g$heights[i-1] = unit(0.4,"cm")

  grobs = which(grepl("strip", g$layout$name))
  for(i in grobs) g$grobs[[i]]$heights <-  unit(1, "npc") 

  plotlist[[j]] <- g
  j <- j+1


}
pdf("baseball.pdf", 7, 5)

for (i in (1:length(plotlist))) {
  grid.arrange(plotlist[[i]])
}

dev.off()
```

Actually, you can even use `grid.arrange` and `ggplotGrob`, without using `facet` to make all more customisable.