# Multiple plots in for loop ignoring par

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra, cowplot, tidyeval

I am trying to generate 10 pairs of plots with a few pairs per page of plots, and am using a `for` loop to construct the pairs. However, the plots are sent to the device as separate plots instead of pages.

The MWE below has identical constructions for base graphics and `ggplot` versions, but the base graphics works and `ggplot` does not. What do I need to do to get the pagination correct in the second version?

```
library(ggplot2)
attach(mtcars)

# correct configuration
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
for (ii in 1:3){
  vars <- c("wt", "disp", "wt")
  plot(get(vars[ii]), mpg)
  hist(get(vars[ii]))
}

# places each on separate plot
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
for (ii in 1:3){
  vars <- c("wt", "disp", "wt")
  p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(get(vars[ii]), mpg)) + geom_point(size=4)
  plot(p)
  p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(get(vars[ii]))) + geom_histogram()
  plot(p)
}

detach(mtcars)
```

Comment: `par` doesn't operate on `ggplot` graphics, only base R. Do you instead want to facet the plots?

Comment: An potential alternative to facets would be `gridExtra::grid.arrange`; see e.g. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249548/side-by-side-plots-with-ggplot2).

Comment: Good to know that `par` is not available. It's not a `facet` problem - different plots. I will have to see if I can make  `gridExtra::grid.arrange` or `cowplot::plot_grid` flexible enough to deal with not naming the individuals plots.

Comment: You might try storing your plots in a list for work with the packages/functions you mentioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way to do it with `cowplot::plot_grid`. The `plot_duo` function uses `tidyeval` approach in [`ggplot2 v3.0.0`](https://www.tidyverse.org/articles/2018/07/ggplot2-3-0-0/)

```r
# install.packages("ggplot2", dependencies = TRUE)

library(rlang)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)

plot_duo <- function(df, plot_var_x, plot_var_y) {

  if (is.character(plot_var_x)) {
    print('character column names supplied, use ensym()')
    plot_var_x <- ensym(plot_var_x)
  } else {
    print('bare column names supplied, use enquo()')
    plot_var_x <- enquo(plot_var_x)
  }

  if (is.character(plot_var_y)) {
    plot_var_y <- ensym(plot_var_y)
  } else {
    plot_var_y <- enquo(plot_var_y)
  }

  pts_plt <- ggplot(df, aes(x = !! plot_var_x, y = !! plot_var_y)) + geom_point(size = 4)
  his_plt <- ggplot(df, aes(x = !! plot_var_x)) + geom_histogram()

  duo_plot <- plot_grid(pts_plt, his_plt, ncol = 2)
}

### use character column names
plot_vars1 <- c("wt", "disp", "wt")
plt1 <- plot_vars1 %>% purrr::map(., ~ plot_duo(mtcars, .x, "mpg"))
#> [1] "character column names supplied, use ensym()"
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
#> [1] "character column names supplied, use ensym()"
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
#> [1] "character column names supplied, use ensym()"
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.

plot_grid(plotlist = plt1, nrow = 3)
```

[image]

```r
### use bare column names
plot_vars2 <- alist(wt, disp, wt)
plt2 <- plot_vars2 %>% purrr::map(., ~ plot_duo(mtcars, .x, "mpg"))
#> [1] "bare column names supplied, use enquo()"
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
#> [1] "bare column names supplied, use enquo()"
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
#> [1] "bare column names supplied, use enquo()"
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.

plot_grid(plotlist = plt2, nrow = 3)
```

[image]

To separate plots into multiple pages, we can use [gridExtra::marrangeGrob](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/vignettes/arrangeGrob.html#multiple-pages-output)

```r
ml1 <- marrangeGrob(plt, nrow = 2, ncol = 1)

# Interactive use
ml1
```

[image]
[image]

```r
# Non-interactive use, multipage pdf
ggsave("multipage.pdf", ml1)
```

Comment: Thank you. This almost works. In my MWE, you can see I am generating 6 plots with 2x2 for the first 'page' and 2x1 on the second. I have adapted your code to my real data, but the `do.call` places all the plots on a single page. Is there a way to force the 2x2 limit so that a separate plot is created for each 4 subplots?