# Creating a plot function in r

Tags: r, function, plot

I am trying to create a plot function to create scatter plots. However it cannot seem to work. I believe the df[,y] and df[,x] seems to be the problem but am not sure whats wrong. Please help!

```
class<-c(1,2,3,4) 
level<-c(1,2,3,4) 
school<-c(2,3,4,5)
score<-c(5,6,7,8)
performance<-c(3,7,6,5)
dataframe = data.frame(class,level,school,score,performance)

plotScatter <- function(x, y, df) {
  plot(df[,y]~df[,x])
}

plotScatter(score, performance, dataframe)
```

Comment: Can also be done with `ggplot2` & tidy evaluation https://stackoverflow.com/a/50930640/786542

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem does indeed originate from the way you subset `df` inside your `plotScatter` function. To plot the two columns against each other, in `df[,x]` the `x` is expected to be a string (and the same for `df[,y]`).

Here are two ways to solve it:

1) call the function with x and y as strings

```
plotScatter <- function(x, y, df) {
  plot(df[,y]~df[,x])
}
plotScatter('score', 'performance', dataframe)
```

2) use `deparse` and `substitute` inside the function to convert the variables to strings

```
plotScatter <- function(x, y, df) {
  x <- deparse(substitute(x))
  y <- deparse(substitute(y))
  plot(df[,y]~df[,x])
}
plotScatter(score, performance, dataframe)
```