# How to accommodate several plots using facet_wrap in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am able to plot several plots that do get plotted in a lattice format with my code. However, there are several of these plots, 77 to be exact so, each plot is totally squished and unreadable. I have tried playing with the width, height, facet_wrap_paginate as well but none seem to give me the output I want. Each plot is a line plot for each subject and EVTEST and there are 77 subjects. 
I want to break the plots in multiple panels of 4X3 or 4X4 and also pages. Also I am outputting it in RTF. I am open to outputting in PDF as well if it works.How do I do it?

Below is a fictitious data, which is the same format that I use as input in my code. what I am trying to plot is line plots for this longitudinal data, where my X axis is VISITDY_D and Y axis is EVSTRESN. I am grouping the plots by creating a concatenated handle (SUBJID_EVTEST_SITE).

```
SUBJID  SITE    EVTEST  EVSTRESN VISITDY_D SIDE
1   AB  ABC 1.1 D00 Left
1   AB  ABC 2.1 D28 Right
1   AB  ABC 2.2 D56 Left
1   AB  ABC 2.3 D84 Left
2   AB  ABC 1.5 D00
2   AB  ABC 1.6 D28 Right


#read the data (csv file)
   donnees <- read.csv(paste0(path_data,"Sample.csv"), sep = ";",header = 
    T,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    Params = c("Phenotype1","Phenotype2")


#PLOTTING FUNCTION 
pf1<-function(subD,tit1){ # subD:Input data, tit1: Title for the plot

subD$SUBJID1 <- 
as.factor(paste0(subD$RANDOID,'_',subD$EVTEST,'_',subD$SITE))
p1 <- ggplot(subD,aes(x = VISITDY_D,y = EVSTRESN, color=SIDE,group=SIDE))    
geom_line(position=position_dodge(width=0.7))+
geom_point() + facet_wrap_paginate(~ SUBJID1, nrow=3,ncol=3,page=1) +
theme()
print(p1)


p1 <- ggplot(subD,aes(x = VISITDY_D,y = EVSTRESN, 
color=SIDE,group=SIDE)) +
geom_line(position=position_dodge(width=0.7))+
geom_point() + facet_wrap(~ SUBJID1) + theme()
print(p1)
}

# OUTPUT; Calling the plotting function in RTF 


oP <- /output_directory

   setwd(oP)

   rtf <- RTF(file = paste0("TEST_","individual profiles.rtf"))
   addTOC(rtf)
   addPageBreak(rtf)


 for(s in 1:length(Params)){

 dat = subset(donnees,donnees$EVTEST %in% Params[s])

 SUBJID1 <-as.factor(paste0(dat$RANDOID,'_',dat$EVTEST,'_',dat$SITE))

 tit1<-paste0(Params[s])
 addHeader(rtf,tit1,font.size = 4, TOC.level = 1)
 addPlot(rtf, plot.fun=pf1, subD= dat,tit1= tit1, width= 7, height=5.2, 
 res=250)
  }

done(rtf)
```

Comment: Have you looked here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39736655/ggplot2-plots-over-multiple-pages

Comment: "I have tried playing with the width, height, facet_wrap_paginate as well but none seem to give me the output I want" implies you have something specific in mind. To help people address your question more usefully, could you please clarify what you're looking for or what the shortfalls were of the approaches you've tried?

Comment: Jon, Thank you for the comments. I tried the code in the link you shared. The output of the code is exactly what I need. However I am getting an error: Error in gList(`75_Erythema_Face` = list(grobs = list(list(x = 0.5, y = 0.5,  : 
  only 'grobs' allowed in "gList". I will appreciate any help to resolve this error.