# How to align layers (density plot and vertical line) in a single ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, density-plot

I am trying to adjust the layers of a plot that uses both `stat_function` and `geom_vline`. My problem is that the vertical line is not perfectly aligned with the green area:

[Density plot with a vertical line (not aligned)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8eNm.png)

[image]

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13294952/left-align-two-graph-edges-ggplot) post I saw a solution to align two separate plots, however, in my case I want to align then in the same plot.

```
all_mean <- mean(mtcars$wt,na.rm = T)%>% round(2)
all_sd <- sd(mtcars$wt,na.rm = T)%>% round(2)
my_score <- mtcars[1,"wt"]


dd <- function(x) { dnorm(x, mean=all_mean, sd=all_sd) }

z <- (my_score - all_mean)/all_sd

pc <- round(100*(pnorm(z)), digits=0)

t1 <- paste0(as.character(pc),"th percentile")

p33 <- all_mean + (qnorm(0.3333) * all_sd)
p67 <- all_mean + (qnorm(0.6667) * all_sd)

funcShaded <- function(x, lower_bound) {
  y = dnorm(x, mean = all_mean, sd = all_sd)
  y[x < lower_bound] <- NA
  return(y)
}

greenShaded <- function(x, lower_bound) {
  y = dnorm(x, mean = all_mean, sd = all_sd)
  y[x > (all_mean*2)] <- NA
  return(y)
}

ggplot(data.frame(x=c(min(mtcars$wt-2), max(mtcars$wt+2))), aes(x=x)) +
  stat_function(fun=dd, colour="black") +
  stat_function(fun = greenShaded, args = list(lower_bound = pc), 
                geom = "area", fill = "green", alpha = 1)+
    stat_function(fun = funcShaded, args = list(lower_bound = my_score), 
                geom = "area", fill = "white", alpha = .9)+
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=my_score), colour="black")
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`stat_function` chooses `n` points along your range, by default 101. This means you only have limited resolution for your curve. Simply increase `n` for the `funcShaded` layer.

```
ggplot(data.frame(x=c(min(mtcars$wt-2), max(mtcars$wt+2))), aes(x=x)) +
  stat_function(fun=dd, colour="black") +
  stat_function(fun = greenShaded, args = list(lower_bound = pc), 
                geom = "area", fill = "green", alpha = 1)+
  stat_function(fun = funcShaded, args = list(lower_bound = my_score), 
                geom = "area", fill = "white", alpha = .9, n = 1e3)+
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=my_score), colour="black")
```

[image]