# Fix axis label length in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4), 
                 y1 = c(1, 3, 2, 4), 
                 y2 = c(3000, 2000, 4000, 1000))
label_1 = c("1", "2", "3") %>% format(width = 5, justify = "right")
label_2 = c("1000", "2000", "3000") %>% format(width = 5, justify = "right")
p1 <- df %>% ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y1))+
  geom_line()+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(1, 2, 3), 
                     labels = label_1)
p2 <- df %>% ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y2))+
  geom_line()+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(1000, 2000, 3000), 
                     labels = label_2)
p1
p2
```

[image]
[image]

In the above code, I try to make `p1` and `p2` to have the same length of `y-axis` label, by `format(width = 5)`. In the actual graph, labels in `p1` are still shorter than those in `p2`.

By trial and error, I get the right length when setting `width =8`.

```
label_3 = c("1", "2", "3") %>% format(width = 8, justify = "right")
p1 <- df %>% ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y1))+
  geom_line()+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(1, 2, 3), 
                     labels = label_3)
p1
```

[image]

Could someone please explain this or guide me to the relevant previous posts?

Comment: Relevant post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13294952/left-align-two-graph-edges-ggplot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular space does not have the same width as a digits (in non-monospaced fonts). Unicode has a 'figure space' that has 'tabular width', i.e. the same width as digits. If you make a helper function that replaces spaces with the tabular widths (`\u2007`), both plots should have the same size for their y-axis. The function:

```r
pad_numbers <- function(x, width, justify = "right") {
  x <- format(x, width = width, justify = justify)
  gsub(" ", "\u2007", x)
}
```

In action:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4), 
                 y1 = c(1, 3, 2, 4), 
                 y2 = c(3000, 2000, 4000, 1000))

label_1 = c("1", "2", "3") %>% pad_numbers(width = 5, justify = "right")
label_2 = c("1000", "2000", "3000") %>% pad_numbers(width = 5, justify = "right")
p1 <- df %>% ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y1))+
  geom_line()+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(1, 2, 3), 
                     labels = label_1)
p2 <- df %>% ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y2))+
  geom_line()+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(1000, 2000, 3000), 
                     labels = label_2)

p1
```

[image]

```r
p2
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Lastly, if you want the y-axis to have the same width for plot composition purposes, I recommend the {ragg} package, which does a good job at aligning the panels between two plots. This wouldn't require the helper function we wrote at the beginning.

Comment: Brilliant! It works perfectly for my purpose. I use it to generate many individual images for a video. Life is easier with smart people around. Thank you.

Comment: Great, glad it helped. If you're using {gganimate} for animating plots, you typically wouldn't have to worry about the dimensions changing over the course of time.

Comment: I use ggplot to generate individual images, and then Python `moviepy` to produce final videos.