# Dual plot sharing the same x-axis in ggplot2

Tags: r

I have a dataset in this format.

```
head(sppec.p)
    Wavelength_.nm.      Mean     Lower     Upper Species Feature_selection Count
1             400 0.1467549 0.1290778 0.2758327    ALAL            T-test     0
2             405 0.1454303 0.1271905 0.2726207    ALAL            T-test     0
3             410 0.1464431 0.1290472 0.2754903    ALAL            T-test     0
4             415 0.1468586 0.1298166 0.2766753    ALAL            T-test     0
5             420 0.1485061 0.1310419 0.2795480    ALAL            T-test     0
6             425 0.1517019 0.1342690 0.2859708    ALAL            T-test     0
```

I originally planned on doing a dual-axis graph, but after searching here, I realized that it was "not possible" in `ggplot` and many advised against such plots. Therefore I have settled for a facet plot. I tried to do the individual plots first but I cannot figure out how to use `facet_wrap` and `scales = "free_y"` to get the 2 plots of identical x-axis but different y-axis.

Code for the individual graphs:

```
  myplot<-ggplot(sppec.p, aes(x=Wavelength_.nm., y=Mean, group=Species, linetype =   Species,
ymin = Lower, ymax =  Upper)) +
 geom_ribbon(alpha = 0.2,fill='gray') +
 geom_line() +  theme_bw() +scale_fill_grey(start = 0.1, end = 0.9) +
 opts(panel.background = theme_rect(fill='grey80')) +
 ylim(0,3)

myplot + theme_bw ()+ opts(axis.line = theme_segment(colour = "black"),
  panel.grid.major = theme_blank(),
  panel.grid.minor = theme_blank())
```

...which produces
[image]

And the second graph:

```
  cum.totals<-ggplot(sppec.p, aes(Wavelength_.nm., y=Count, fill =     factor(Feature_selection))) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
   cum.totals + theme_bw() +scale_fill_grey(start = 0.1, end = 0.9)+
opts(axis.line = theme_segment(colour = "black"),
panel.grid.major = theme_blank(),  
panel.grid.minor = theme_blank(),
panel.border = theme_blank(),
panel.background = theme_blank())
```

Graph produced:

[image]

Though both y-axis appear numerically equivalent, they represent different values.

I am not very familiar with `ggplot` and I would like to know how to use `facet_wrap` or any other function that would give me the 2 plots on the sharing the same a-axis but in 2 facets. Is it possible to make my code more efficient?

So essentially the layout of the final output would be something like this:
[image]

Comment: Are you trying to get two y axes for count and mean plotted against the same x axis for wavelength?

Comment: Essentially yes. Something similar to the response posted by Mark Parker found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12448428/align-multiple-ggplot2-plots-with-grid). But I would need the relevant legends next to the corresponding plots.

Comment: Like i mentioned in my answer, the two y values in your question are not comparable, whereas in the linked question, they probably are. Therefore plotting the both of them in the same chart is not a good pactice. And Matt's answer uses `facet` which is probably not the right trick here as explained in my answer as well.

Comment: I think I found the solution to a similar problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14590111/how-to-control-plot-width-in-gridextra)

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25451066/680068)

Answer (score 1):

`Facet` is useful when you have the same type of chart broken down into multiple categories. Your situation is different. Check out the help entry on the various `facet_grid` and `facet_wrap` to see the difference. Here's something to help you get started -

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point() + facet_grid(. ~ cyl)
```

[image]

i'm not a big fan of two different y axes against the same x axis (which is what you're trying to do there, if I understand correctly). Instead, try `gridExtra::arrangeGrob` with the argument `ncol = 1` to have your charts stacked vertically on top of another allowing you to have identical x axes on top of one another and achieving a similar effect.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will try to search for examples on how to use `gridExtra::arrangeGrob`. Just for clarification, I do not want a dual y-axis graph (one graph with both the vertical bars chart and the line graph). For example, instead of having one row and 3 columns, as in the example you have, I am seeking 2 rows and one column (if it makes more sense to you???)

Comment: I just remembered, you could also try plain ol' `rbind`.

Comment: `rbind` on the ggplot objects? That would be interesting

Comment: Check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16255579/how-can-i-make-consistent-width-plots-in-ggplot-with-legends